# JFrame or Class Object?

Tags: user-interface

I was wondering whether it is necessary to create a JFrame object or can I simply create a LoanCalculator object to invoke JFrame methods? In GUI code I've done before, creating a JFrame object (ex. JFrame frame = new JFrame()) or class object works and the program runs fine.

What exactly is the difference and is there any significance to create a JFrame object instead of a class one? (The only relevant part of my question is code in my main class)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LoanCalculator extends JFrame{
        private JButton jbtCompute = new JButton("Compute Payment");

    public LoanCalculator(){
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
            panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 2));
        panel1.add(new JLabel("Annual Interest Rate"));
        panel1.add(new JTextField(8));
        panel1.add(new JLabel("Number of Years"));
        panel1.add(new JTextField(8));
        panel1.add(new JLabel("Loan Amount"));
        panel1.add(new JTextField(8));
        panel1.add(new JLabel("Monthly Payment"));
        panel1.add(new JTextField(8));
        panel1.add(new JLabel("Total Payment"));
        panel1.add(new JTextField(8));

        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        panel2.add(jbtCompute);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        LoanCalculator frame = new LoanCalculator();

        frame.setTitle("Loan Calculator");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if `LoanCalculator` is a subclass of `JFrame`, then it inherits all methods and variables that belong to `JFrame` (plus whatever methods and variables you add to `LoanCalculator` yourself).    Anything that you can do to a regular `JFrame`, you will be able to do to a `LoanCalculator`.

The code you pasted looks fine to me (except that you never add `panel1` or `panel2` to your frame's contentPane).